# How do you declare multiple characteristics in Web Bluetooth?

Tags: next.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

**I have no clue how to implement multiple characteristics:**

Currently my code works perfectly when a single characteristic is declared/implemented:

```
   .then((service) => {
    pushlog("Getting Shutdown Characteristic...");
    shdn = service.getCharacteristic(
      "33ca7a02-c95f-4bca-a8bb-6692930216d0"
    ); return shdn;
```

However, when I attempt to implement multiple characteristics (the plain-text uuid's work with web bluetooth):

```
.then((service) => {
    pushlog("Getting Characteristic...");
    heart_rate_measurement = service.getCharacteristic(
      "heart_rate_measurement"
    );
    temperature_measurement = service.getCharacteristic(
      "temperature_measurement"
    );
    shdn = service.getCharacteristic(
      "33ca7a02-c95f-4bca-a8bb-6692930216d0"
    );
    stim = service.getCharacteristic(
      "b71ce29e-7353-40bf-a4dd-b0c03593e0ba"
    );
    battery = service.getCharacteristic("battery_level");

    return (
      shdn, heart_rate_measurement, temperature_measurement, stim, battery
    );
  })
```

My read/write code doesn't work -

```
.then((shdn) => {
    pushlog("Writing to Shutdown Characteristic...");

    // Writing 1 is the signal to reset energy expended.
    let resetEnergyExpended = Uint8Array.of(0x01);
    return shdn.writeValue(resetEnergyExpended);
  })
```

Am I declaring these additional characteristics incorrectly? All the resources I see are for android BLE and not web bluetooth. I saw some solutions using classes, however, I'm using next.js and I'm clueless of how to implement vanilla JS classes into react.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? This code probably generates an error which will help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`service.getCharacteristic()` returns a `Promise` and so in order to have your program properly wait for all of the promises you return to resolve before executing the callback passed to `then()` you need to wrap the list in      `Promise.all()`. The callback will get a list which you then need to unpack to get all the individual characteristic objects.

Destructuring makes this relatively easy to write:

```
.then((service) => {
    pushlog("Getting Characteristic...");
    heart_rate_measurement = service.getCharacteristic(
      "heart_rate_measurement"
    );
    temperature_measurement = service.getCharacteristic(
      "temperature_measurement"
    );
    shdn = service.getCharacteristic(
      "33ca7a02-c95f-4bca-a8bb-6692930216d0"
    );
    stim = service.getCharacteristic(
      "b71ce29e-7353-40bf-a4dd-b0c03593e0ba"
    );
    battery = service.getCharacteristic("battery_level");

    return Promise.all([
      shdn, heart_rate_measurement, temperature_measurement, stim, battery
    ]);
  })
.then(([shdn, heart_rate_measurement, temperature_measurement, stim, battery]) => {
    pushlog("Writing to Shutdown Characteristic...");

    // Writing 1 is the signal to reset energy expended.
    let resetEnergyExpended = Uint8Array.of(0x01);
    return shdn.writeValue(resetEnergyExpended);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks so much Reilly! I really appreciate your assistance.